# Yii2: Override 3rd party mail views

Tags: yii2, yii2-extension, yii2-module

How do we override mail view files of a 3rd party module/component?

Let's assume a module is using the following code to send an email:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose([
    'html'  => '@myvendor/mymodule/mail/email-html',
    'text'  => '@myvendor/mymodule/mail/email-text',
])
    ->setTo([$email => $name])
    ->setSubject('Hi');
    ->send();
```

How would we override these individual email views `@myvendor/mymodule/mail/email-html` and `@myvendor/mymodule/mail/email-text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override these two aliases in your config:

```
'aliases' => [
    '@myvendor/mymodule/mail/email-html' => '@app/views/mail/email-html',
    '@myvendor/mymodule/mail/email-text' => '@app/views/mail/email-text',
],
```

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Configure and rewrite the **$viewPath** property in the mail file in the module.

example:

```
 public $viewPath = '@myvendor/mymodule/mail';
```

First, create new html and text files. Create both files.
**Create both files**.

- mail/newHTML
- mail/trxt/NewTEXT

  ```
     $mailer = Yii::$app->mailer;
     $mailer->viewPath = $this->viewPath;
     $mailer->getView()->theme = Yii::$app->view->theme;
      return $mailer->compose(['html' => $view, 'text' => 'text/' . $view], $params)
          ->setTo($to)
          ->setFrom($this->sender)
          ->setSubject($subject)
          ->send();
  ```

> If you want to change the path for only one:
>   Use before code:

```
Yii :: $ app-> mailer-> viewPath = '@ myvendor / newPath';

Yii::$app->mailer->compose([ #code...
```

If the VIEW file: Only need to change the name for HTML and TEXT file, **(both)**

> Update:
>
> It can be override or through a component and ...

```
//new file: path\widgets\Mailer.php
namespace path\widgets;
use yourpath\Mailer as DefaultMailer;  //path:mymodule/mail
class Mailer extends DefaultMailer{
    public $viewPath = '@myvendor/mymodule/mail';
    public function changeviewPath($_path){
        $this->viewPath; = $_path;
    }
}
```

// for use. Changes

```
use path\widgets\Maile;  // New path
// Use before the usual code
$mailer->changeviewPath('newpath\mail');
```

To change the address of the files in the component. Depending on your email module, it varies

example:

```
'modules' => [
        'myMudul' => [
            'class' => 'PathModule\Module',
            'mailer' => [
                #code ..
        ],
   ],
    ...
```

Comment: This will override *all* mail view files of the module. I only want to override those specific ones.

Comment: I can't "Use before code" because it's handled by a 3rd party vendor package. I can't modify that.

Comment: I've put a code example. Hope to help. With respect.